# ViewBag return null in Extension Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use my ViewBag in my _Layout, because all my views have similar data. So here what I do:

In my View:

```
ViewBag.MetaKeywords = Model.MetaKeywords
```

I have an extension class binded on the HtmlHelper

```
public static string MetaKeywords(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return helper.ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.MetaKeyWords;
}
```

And in my _Layout:

```
@Html.MetaKeywords()
```

The problem is my extension method returns null. Why I use an extension method instead of `@ViewBag.MetaKeyWords`? Because some other functions have logic and we want to share it between ourself.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are setting `ViewBag.MetaDescription` but you trying to access `ViewBag.MetaKeyWords` in your helper is it a typo in your sample code? Because the property names should match.

Comment: Sorry, I made made an error in my post, I've modified it and so my problem persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using Razor the `ViewBag/ViewData` properties which were set in the View can be accessed with `helper.ViewData` instead of `helper.ViewContext. ...`:

```
 public static string MetaKeywords(this HtmlHelper helper)
 {
     return (string) helper.ViewData["MetaKeyWords"];
 }
```

Note: The `ViewBag` is just a dynamic wrapper around the `ViewData` dictionary.

Or if you do the `ViewBag.MetaKeywords = Model.MetaKeywords` in the Controller then your original extension method should also work.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I can't remember where, but something pointed me to use helper.ViewContext to access the ViewBag, which was incorrect, so THANK YOU!!